# Transmitting/Sending big packet safely using TcpClient/Socket

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I am writing a TCP based client that need to send and receive data. I have used the `Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)` provided for Socket class by the .NET Framework.

After being connected to the socket, I start wait for data on the socket using `BeginReceive`.

Now, while I am waiting for the data on the Socket, I may need to send data over the socket. And the send method can be called multiple times,

So i have make sure that

- All the bytes from previous `Send` call is entirely sent.
- The way i am sending the Data is safe considering that, while a data send is in progress, any call to send data can be made.

**This is my first work on socket, So is my approach right to send data ?**

```
    private readonly object writeLock = new object();
    public void Send(NetworkCommand cmd)
    {
        var data = cmd.ToBytesWithLengthPrefix();
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AsyncDataSent, data);
    }

    private int bytesSent;
    private void AsyncDataSent(object odata)
    {
        lock (writeLock)
        {
            var data = (byte[])odata;
            int total = data.Length;
            bytesSent = 0;
            int buf = Globals.BUFFER_SIZE;
            while (bytesSent < total)
            {
                if (total - bytesSent < Globals.BUFFER_SIZE)
                {
                    buf = total - bytesSent;
                }
                IAsyncResult ar = socket.BeginSend(data, bytesSent, buf, SocketFlags.None, DataSentCallback, data);
                ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
            }
        }
    }
```

How object is changed into `byte[]`, sometimes the `NetworkCommand` can be as big as **0.5 MB**

```
    public byte[] ToBytesWithLengthPrefix()
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        try
        {
            Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, this, PrefixStyle.Fixed32);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.Close();
            stream.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

---

Complete class

```
namespace Cybotech.Network
{
    public delegate void ConnectedDelegate(IPEndPoint ep);
    public delegate void DisconnectedDelegate(IPEndPoint ep);
    public delegate void CommandReceivedDelagate(IPEndPoint ep, NetworkCommand cmd);
}


using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using Cybotech.Helper;
using Cybotech.IO;

namespace Cybotech.Network
{
    public class ClientState : IDisposable
    {
        private int _id;
        private int _port;
        private IPAddress _ip;
        private IPEndPoint _endPoint;
        private Socket _socket;
        private ForwardStream _stream;
        private byte[] _buffer;

        public ClientState(IPEndPoint endPoint, Socket socket)
        {
            Init(endPoint, socket);
        }

        private void Init(IPEndPoint endPoint, Socket socket)
        {
            _endPoint = endPoint;
            _ip = _endPoint.Address;
            _port = _endPoint.Port;
            _id = endPoint.GetHashCode();
            _socket = socket;
            _stream = new ForwardStream();
            _buffer = new byte[Globals.BUFFER_SIZE];
        }

        public int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
        }

        public int Port
        {
            get { return _port; }
        }

        public IPAddress Ip
        {
            get { return _ip; }
        }

        public IPEndPoint EndPoint
        {
            get { return _endPoint; }
        }

        public Socket Socket
        {
            get { return _socket; }
        }

        public ForwardStream Stream
        {
            get { return _stream; }
        }

        public byte[] Buffer
        {
            get { return _buffer; }
            set { _buffer = value; }
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (_stream != null)
                {
                    _stream.Close();
                    _stream.Dispose();
                }

                if (_socket != null)
                {
                    _socket.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using Cybotech.Command;
using Cybotech.Network;

namespace ExamServer.Network
{
    public class TcpServer : IDisposable
    {

        private Socket socket;
        private bool secure;

        private readonly Dictionary<IPEndPoint, ClientState> clients = new Dictionary<IPEndPoint, ClientState>();

        //public events
        #region Events

        public event CommandDelegate CommandReceived;
        public event ConnectedDelegate ClientAdded;
        public event DisconnectedDelegate ClientRemoved;

        #endregion

        //event invokers
        #region Event Invoke methods

        protected virtual void OnCommandReceived(IPEndPoint ep, NetworkCommand command)
        {
            CommandDelegate handler = CommandReceived;
            if (handler != null) handler(ep, command);
        }

        protected virtual void OnClientAdded(IPEndPoint ep)
        {
            ConnectedDelegate handler = ClientAdded;
            if (handler != null) handler(ep);
        }

        protected virtual void OnClientDisconnect(IPEndPoint ep)
        {
            DisconnectedDelegate handler = ClientRemoved;
            if (handler != null) handler(ep);
        }

        #endregion

        //public property
        public string CertificatePath { get; set; }

        public TcpServer(EndPoint endPoint, bool secure)
        {
            StartServer(endPoint, secure);
        }

        public TcpServer(IPAddress ip, int port, bool secure)
        {
            StartServer(new IPEndPoint(ip, port), secure);
        }

        public TcpServer(string host, int port, bool secure)
        {
            StartServer(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(host), port), secure);
        }

        private void StartServer(EndPoint ep, bool ssl)
        {
            socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socket.Bind(ep);
            socket.Listen(150);
            this.secure = ssl;

            socket.BeginAccept(AcceptClientCallback, null);
        }

        private void AcceptClientCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Socket client = socket.EndAccept(ar);
            var ep = (IPEndPoint) client.RemoteEndPoint;
            var state = new ClientState(ep, client);
            if (secure)
            {
                //TODO : handle client for ssl authentication
            }

            //add client to 
            clients.Add(ep, state);
            OnClientAdded(ep);
            client.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveDataCallback, state);

            //var thread = new Thread(ReceiveDataCallback);
            //thread.Start(state);
        }

        private void ReceiveDataCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            ClientState state = (ClientState)ar.AsyncState;

            try
            {
                var bytesRead = state.Socket.EndReceive(ar);
                state.Stream.Write(state.Buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                // check available commands
                while (state.Stream.LengthPrefix > 0)
                {
                    NetworkCommand cmd = NetworkCommand.CreateFromStream(state.Stream);
                    OnCommandReceived(state.EndPoint, cmd);
                }

                //start reading data again
                state.Socket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveDataCallback, state);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                if (ex.NativeErrorCode.Equals(10054))
                {
                    RemoveClient(state.EndPoint);
                }
            }
        }

        private void RemoveClient(IPEndPoint ep)
        {

            OnClientDisconnect(ep);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                //TODO : dispose all the client related socket stuff
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AsyncDataSent, data); - that call in send may cause subtle bugs. Do you require send to work in a FIFO fashion? i.e. if two send calls A and B come very close to each other (in that order), A should happen first and then B? I don't think ThreadPool.Queue guarantees FIFO - so you may have a hard to catch bug...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same client won't be able to send data to you unless he finishes sending the current bytes.

So on the server side, you will receive the completed data no interrupted by other new messages from that client, but take in consideration that not all the message sent will be received by one hit if it is too big, but still, it is one message in the end after receiving is finished.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using TCP, the network protocol will ensure that packets are received in the same order as sent.
Regarding thread safety it depends a bit on the actual class which you are using for sending. The declaration part is missing in your provided code fragment.
Given by the name you seem to use Socket and this is thread-safe, so every send is actually atomic, if you use any flavor of Stream, then it is not thread-safe and you need some form of synchronization like a lock, which you are currently using anyway.
If you are sending large packets, then it is important to split the receiving and processing part into two different threads. The TCP buffer is actually a lot smaller than one would think and unfortunately it is not covered inside the logs when it is full as the protocol will keep performing resend until everything has been received.

Comment: i have updated the codes with complete Classes used, may be now you can have a closer look, i actually only have doubt on the Send method, that is it sending data properly

Comment: Ok - I think you can safely use just one send instead of working with a buffer size. As said before I would more look into having a read buffer on the server size as this is the side which is more likely to be overloaded. Sending in smaller packages will not help, it is all about the receiver cleaning its buffer asap. As everything is buffered, it does not matter, that the client sends chuncks.